# Why do I get a equaly spaced, square-type true-prediction plot in deep learning (regression)?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression

I use Tensorflow 2.0 for regression and get poor performance on the training loss. Plotting the true values vs. predictions I always get this strange behavior:

[image: True vs. Predictions]

[image: 6000 samples]
I have a model with two inputs and one output. One input is a three-dimensional voxel image (None,32,32,32,1), the second is a numeric input (None,2). The output is numeric as well (None,6). For the first I am using a simple CNN consisting of "CNN-CNN-MAX...", the second input goes through some FC. I concatenate the two branches and go through some additional FC. I was able to overfit on small batch sizes and achieved a < 0.1% relative error for batch size 32. I am using Adam. All layers have LeakyRElu activation. No regularization. I use z-score scaling for the input. I take a fixed amount of samples and shuffle these in every epoch. I tried different learning rates, optimizers, architectures, mean-square or mean-absolut loss, etc. The overfitted samples showed perfect behavior in true vs. predictions (linear correlation).

For more samples, I get the behavior in the picture. I think it is a very "special" behavior, but I wasn't able to find something similar in the net. The mean-relative error is about 10% for this behavior.

Does anybody saw this kind of behavior? What could be the cause? I think I tried everything. I thought it was related to shuffling, but deactivating did not help. Any suggestions?